# Compile errors after installing VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I was working on VS2013 on a class library project that references MVC dll from the following location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

Then I uninstalled VS2013 then installed VS2015. Now my project is demanding the MVC dll

[image]

Please note that the following path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\

is missing from my computer.

The following compile error appears on build:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Remove them and add them again.

Comment: I can't add them again because the old path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4  is missing from my computer

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that MVC4 was bundled together with visual studio 2013 and thus is also removed. You could try to reinstall it yourself using the [web platform installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) or removing the dependencies and re-adding them using nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/4.0.40804) `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.40804`

Comment: If I installed the package then there will be a (packages.config) file in my project which I do not want

Comment: offtopic: what is your concern for the packages.config file / usage of nuget?

Comment: This project is a team project, I can not add the packages.config file :)